# Retrieve selected radio button values dynamically by variable to name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button, computer-science

When I manually use a string to name,

```
var checkedAnswer = $('input[name="1"]:checked').val();
```

it works..

but I'd like to use dynamic index value in the loop.
However, somehow the returned value is undefined.

```
function myFunction(){
  var numberOfQuestions = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfQuestions; i++) {
    var index = i.toString();
    var fieldset = document.getElementsByName(index);
    var checkedAnswer = $('input[name=index]:checked').val(); 
}
```

How can I retrieve values from radio buttons dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the string `index`, you want to use the variable `index` like this:

```
$(`input[name=${index}]:checked`).val();
```

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are strings wrapped within tick marks, you can then use `${my_var}` within them to use **variables** or other javascript **statements**.